# How to highlight specific subpanel in a master JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am building a GUI for a maze-based game.

The main JPanel is made up of smaller JPanels I call Tiles. My goal is to have a specific tile JPanel be highlighted when the player is in that cell. It would look something like this:

[image]

Here is the code for an MRE. I think you can use any 3 test.png with it. I think its not working because the JLabel with the image on it is covering up the highlight.

```java
public class testGui extends JFrame {
  
  private final Board board;
  
  public testGui() {
    
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);

    this.board = new Board();
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(board);
    this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
  
  
  
  
  public ImageIcon getImage(int i) {
    

    try {
      
      BufferedImage imageBase = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(String.format("/images/test%d.png", i)));
      
      int width = imageBase.getWidth();
      int height = imageBase.getHeight();
      
      BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
      g.drawImage(imageBase, 0, 0, null);        
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(combined);
        return icon;

       
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DungeonGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

  }

   return null; 
  }
  
  private class Board extends JPanel {

    public Board() {

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        
        Tile tile = new Tile(i);
        
        cellPanel.setName(String.format("%d", i));
        add(tile, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        if (gbc.gridx >= 3) {
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
        }

if (i ==2) {

//TODO highlight JUST this tile


    }
    }
    
    
   
  }
  

  private class Tile extends JPanel  {
    

    private int i;
    private JLabel label;
    private Color highlight = new Color(0, 0, 255, 128);
    
    public CellPanel(int i) {
      super();
      this.i = i;
      
      this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
      
      ImageIcon imageIcon = getImage(i);
      
      this.label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
      this.add(label);
      
      setOpaque(false);
      
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      
      super.paintComponent(g);
      
      ImageIcon imageIcon = getImage(i);
      
      this.label.setIcon(imageIcon);
      
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      
      g2d.setColor(highlight);
      g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      g2d.dispose();
      

    }
    
  }
  
  @Override
  public void refresh() {
    
    this.repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void makeVisible() {

    this.setVisible(true);
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is your [mre]? You have been asked for an MRE in your other questions so it time to learn how to post one with your question.  Create a simple example with a JFrame, your JLabel (with text) and the custom painting code to attempt to highlight the label. If it works, great then you apply the solution to your real application. If it doesn't work then you have your MRE to post here. Note a painting method should only paint the current state of the component. This means your logic should NOT be setting the Icon in the painting method. This is why you need the MRE, to learn the basics first.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to set up an MRE now. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: Also note in your other question two people suggest you do NOT need a separate panel. Your "Tile" can just extend JLabel with your custom painting and you add the label to your "Board" class.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use paintComponent to repaint my maze after every action without having the "tiles" subpanels. I'm sure theres a way of doing it with paintComponent being in the main panel.

Comment: You don't do anything special. There is not difference if the "Tile" class extends JPanel or JLabel. When the the "Tile" component is repainted the paintComponent() method will be invoked automatically. If it isn't you have a big painting issue which is why I stated you need to first learn painting basics before trying to build an application.

Comment: Don't set the state of the label from within the `paintComponent` method - the original code only overrode `paintComponent` to demonstrate that the `MouseListener` would work

Comment: @MadProgrammer I moved the logic to the master panel. Does JPanel have methods similar to .setColor() and .fill()?

Comment: @Nova Custom painting is custom painting, see [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) for more details. You might also find [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) helpful

Comment: *"I couldn't figure out how to use paintComponent to repaint my maze after every action without having the "tiles" subpanels. I'm sure theres a way of doing it with paintComponent being in the main panel. "* That doesn't make any sense, there's no difference in how a panel or label is repainted.  If you've modified a container or it's layout, then call `revalidate` and `repaint` to trigger new layout and paint pass

Comment: (1-) This is NOT an MRE. The code doesn't compile. We don't have access to your ReadOnlyModel or your images. And neither of them are relative to your stated question of "highlighting" a Tile. All you need is a JFrame and a "Tile" object. You don't need a "Board" class or anything else. You first need to learn how to do custom painting. Once you understand how to paint a highlight on a single Tile it will be easy to add multiple Tile objects to the frame.

Answer (score 2):

Never update the state of component from within a `paint` method, this is going to cause no end of issues for you in the long run.

If you want more control over the image, then you might consider creating a custom component capable of painting the image and then performing what ever overlay/highlights you want, for example

```
public class CellPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private boolean highlighted;

    public CellPane(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        BufferedImage image = getImage();
        return image == null ? new Dimension(128, 128) : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    public boolean isHighlighted() {
        return highlighted;
    }

    public void setHighlighted(boolean highlighted) {
        this.highlighted = highlighted;
        repaint();
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        if (isHighlighted()) {
            g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255, 128));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Maze.Direction> directions = new ArrayList<>(32);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);

                System.out.println(directions.size());

                Maze maze = new DefaultMaze(5, 6, directions);

                MazeGui frame = new MazeGui(maze);
                frame.addClickListener(null);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Maze {

        enum Direction {
            EAST_SOUTH("EastSouth.png"), EAST_SOUTH_WEST("EastSouthWest.png"), SOUTH_WEST("SouthWest.png"),
            NORTH_EAST_SOUTH("NorthEastSouth.png"), NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST("NorthEastSouthWest.png"),
            NORTH_SOUTH_WEST("NorthSouthWest.png"), NORTH_SOUTH("NorthSouth.png"), NORTH("North.png");

            private BufferedImage image;

            private Direction(String name) {
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/" + name));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            public BufferedImage getImage() {
                return image;
            }

        }

        public int getRows();

        public int getColumns();

        public Direction getRoomDirections(int index);
    }

    public class DefaultMaze implements Maze {

        int rows;
        int columns;

        private List<Direction> directions;

        public DefaultMaze(int rows, int columns, List<Direction> directions) {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.columns = columns;
            this.directions = directions;
        }

        public int getRows() {
            return rows;
        }

        public int getColumns() {
            return columns;
        }

        @Override
        public Direction getRoomDirections(int index) {
            return directions.get(index);
        }
    }

    // Missing code
    public interface DungeonController {
    }

    public class MazeGui extends JFrame {

        private final Board board;

        public MazeGui(Maze m) {
            this.setSize(600, 600);
            this.setResizable(false);

            this.board = new Board(m);
            JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(board);
            this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            setTitle("Dungeon Escape");
        }

        public Board getBoard() {
            return board;
        }

        public void addClickListener(DungeonController listener) {
            Board board = getBoard();
            board.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    board.highlightCellAt(e.getPoint());
                }
            });
        }

        private class Board extends JPanel {

            private Maze maze;
            private CellPane lastHighlightedCell = null;

            public Board(Maze maze) {
                this.maze = maze;
                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;

                for (int index = 0; index < maze.getRows() * maze.getColumns(); index++) {
                    Maze.Direction direction = maze.getRoomDirections(index);
                    // Could use direction directly
                    CellPane cellPane = new CellPane(direction.getImage());
                    cellPane.setName(direction.name());
                    add(cellPane, gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                    if (gbc.gridx >= maze.getColumns()) {
                        gbc.gridx = 0;
                        gbc.gridy++;
                    }
                }
            }

            public void highlightCellAt(Point p) {
                Component component = getComponentAt(p);
                if (component instanceof CellPane) {
                    CellPane cell = (CellPane) component;
                    cell.setHighlighted(true);
                    if (lastHighlightedCell != null && cell != lastHighlightedCell) {
                        lastHighlightedCell.setHighlighted(false);
                    }
                    lastHighlightedCell = cell;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class CellPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;
        private boolean highlighted;

        public CellPane(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            BufferedImage image = getImage();
            return image == null ? new Dimension(128, 128) : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        public boolean isHighlighted() {
            return highlighted;
        }

        public void setHighlighted(boolean highlighted) {
            this.highlighted = highlighted;
            repaint();
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            if (isHighlighted()) {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255, 128));
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

## Another approach...

Another approach might to take advantage of `GridBagLayout`.  You can get the constraints used to layout out a given component and then re-use them to apply a "overlay" panel to the same location.

This means you can keep the `JLabel` for displaying the maze direction and use a "overlay" component to provide different highlights

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Maze.Direction> directions = new ArrayList<>(32);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH_WEST);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH_SOUTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);
                directions.add(Maze.Direction.NORTH);

                System.out.println(directions.size());

                Maze maze = new DefaultMaze(5, 6, directions);

                MazeGui frame = new MazeGui(maze);
                frame.addClickListener(null);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Maze {

        enum Direction {
            EAST_SOUTH("EastSouth.png"), EAST_SOUTH_WEST("EastSouthWest.png"), SOUTH_WEST("SouthWest.png"),
            NORTH_EAST_SOUTH("NorthEastSouth.png"), NORTH_EAST_SOUTH_WEST("NorthEastSouthWest.png"),
            NORTH_SOUTH_WEST("NorthSouthWest.png"), NORTH_SOUTH("NorthSouth.png"), NORTH("North.png");

            private BufferedImage image;

            private Direction(String name) {
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/" + name));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            public BufferedImage getImage() {
                return image;
            }

        }

        public int getRows();

        public int getColumns();

        public Direction getRoomDirections(int index);
    }

    public class DefaultMaze implements Maze {

        int rows;
        int columns;

        private List<Direction> directions;

        public DefaultMaze(int rows, int columns, List<Direction> directions) {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.columns = columns;
            this.directions = directions;
        }

        public int getRows() {
            return rows;
        }

        public int getColumns() {
            return columns;
        }

        @Override
        public Direction getRoomDirections(int index) {
            return directions.get(index);
        }
    }

    // Missing code
    public interface DungeonController {
    }

    public class MazeGui extends JFrame {

        // Missing code
        public interface DungeonController {
        }

        private final Board board;

        public MazeGui(Maze m) {
            this.setSize(600, 600);
            this.setResizable(false);

            this.board = new Board(m);
            JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(board);
            this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            setTitle("Dungeon Escape");
        }

        public Board getBoard() {
            return board;
        }

        public void addClickListener(DungeonController listener) {
            Board board = getBoard();
            board.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    board.highlightCellAt(e.getPoint());
                }
            });
        }

        private class Board extends JPanel {

            private Maze maze;
            private HighlighPane highlightPane = new HighlighPane();

            public Board(Maze maze) {
                this.maze = maze;
                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;

                for (int index = 0; index < maze.getRows() * maze.getColumns(); index++) {
                    Maze.Direction direction = maze.getRoomDirections(index);
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(direction.getImage()));
                    label.setName(direction.name());
                    add(label, gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                    if (gbc.gridx >= maze.getColumns()) {
                        gbc.gridx = 0;
                        gbc.gridy++;
                    }
                }
            }

            public void highlightCellAt(Point point) {
                Component component = getComponentAt(point);
                remove(highlightPane);
                if (component != null) {
                    GridBagLayout layout = (GridBagLayout) getLayout();
                    GridBagConstraints gbc = layout.getConstraints(component);
                    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
                    add(highlightPane, gbc, 0);
                }
                revalidate();
                repaint(); 
            }
        }
    }

    public class HighlighPane extends JPanel {

        private Color highlight = new Color(0, 0, 255, 128);

        public HighlighPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(highlight);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

## Modification of "MCVE"

The is, yet, another modification of your code. This highlights to me that you've not taken the time to read through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), especially [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html), which highlights the order in which paint methods are chained together.

Basically `paint`

- `paintComponent`
- `paintBorder`
- `paintChildren`

What's important to note here is, `paintComponent` is called FIRST, before any child components are painted.  You also need to beware that it's entirely possible for a child component to under go a paint pass without the parent component been involved.

Sooo, when designing "highlight" or "overlay" solutions, you need to keep this is mind, which is why the first suggestion was to do away with `JLabel` and do it all yourself.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import stackoverflow.Test.ReadOnlyModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                List<List<String>> directions = new ArrayList<>(32);

                List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
                row.add("EastSouth");
                row.add("EastSouthWest");
                row.add("EastSouthWest");
                row.add("EastSouthWest");
                row.add("EastSouthWest");
                row.add("SouthWest");
                directions.add(row);

                row = new ArrayList<>();
                row.add("NorthEastSouth");
                row.add("NorthEastSouthWest");
                row.add("NorthEastSouthWest");
                row.add("NorthEastSouthWest");
                row.add("NorthEastSouthWest");
                row.add("NorthSouthWest");
                directions.add(row);

                row = new ArrayList<>();
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                directions.add(row);

                row = new ArrayList<>();
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                row.add("NorthSouth");
                directions.add(row);

                row = new ArrayList<>();
                row.add("North");
                row.add("North");
                row.add("North");
                row.add("North");
                row.add("North");
                row.add("North");
                directions.add(row);

                System.out.println(directions.size());

                DefaultModel maze = new DefaultModel(5, 6, directions);

                TestGUI frame = new TestGUI(maze);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface ReadOnlyModel {

        public int getRows();

        public int getColumns();

        public String getDirectionAt(int row, int column);

        public Image getImageFor(String direction);
    }

    public class DefaultModel implements ReadOnlyModel {

        int rows;
        int columns;

        private List<List<String>> directions;

        public DefaultModel(int rows, int columns, List<List<String>> directions) {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.columns = columns;
            this.directions = directions;
        }

        public int getRows() {
            return rows;
        }

        public int getColumns() {
            return columns;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDirectionAt(int row, int column) {
            return directions.get(row).get(column);
        }

        @Override
        public Image getImageFor(String direction) {
            try {
                return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(String.format("/images/%s.png", direction)));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(direction);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

        private final Board board;

        public TestGUI(ReadOnlyModel m) {

            this.setSize(600, 600);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setResizable(false);

            this.board = new Board(m);
            JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(board);
            this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        private class Board extends JPanel {

            public Board(ReadOnlyModel m) {

                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;

                int counter = 0;
                for (int row = 0; row < m.getRows(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < m.getColumns(); col++) {
                        String direction = m.getDirectionAt(row, col);
                        Image image = m.getImageFor(direction);
                        Tile tile = new Tile(direction, image);
                        add(tile, gbc);
                        gbc.gridx++;
                        counter++;
                        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                            tile.setHighlighted(true);
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                    gbc.gridx = 0;
                    gbc.gridy++;
                }

            }

            private class Tile extends JPanel {

                private String direction;
                private Color highlight = new Color(0, 0, 255, 128);
                private Image image;

                private boolean highlighted = false;

                public Tile(String direction, Image image) {
                    this.direction = direction;
                    setName(direction);
                    setOpaque(false);
                    this.image = image;
                }

                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    Image image = getImage();
                    return image == null ? new Dimension(128, 128) : new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
                }

                public void setHighlighted(boolean highlighted) {
                    this.highlighted = highlighted;
                }

                public boolean isHighlighted() {
                    return highlighted;
                }

                public Image getImage() {
                    return image;
                }

                public Color getHighlight() {
                    return highlight;
                }

                @Override
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

                    Image image = getImage();
                    if (image != null) {
                        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
                    }

                    if (isHighlighted()) {
                        g2d.setColor(highlight);
                        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                    }
                    g2d.dispose();
                }

            }

//            @Override
//            public void refresh() {
//
//                this.repaint();
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void makeVisible() {
//
//                this.setVisible(true);
//
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your recommended changes to my code in an attempt to highlight every Tile panel. It didn't seem to work. I thought having two classes, one with highlights and one without, as a solution. Then I could add the appropriate class to the Board Jpanel using the logic.

Comment: @Nova In general, if it's not working for you, then I would suggest there's something wrong with the way you're implementing the solution.  I now have 3 runnable examples, all of which work

Comment: @Nova You need to provide a [mcve] before we can offer you with more existence

Comment: ok just provided one! I just don't have the images.

Comment: @Nova *ok just provided one!* - that is NOT an MRE and you ignored every suggestion I provided. You still haven't learned how to basic painting and are trying to write an entire application. Forget about trying to write the entire maze application with your 64 tiles and learn how to create a simple tile where you can control the custom painting. You don't even need an image to test this. All you need is a Tile class that extends JLabel with custom painting. The solution here is too complicated since you don't even have the basic of custom painting down pat. Learn to walk before you run.

Comment: Got rid of the ReadOnlyModel. I understand that this may be overly complicated, but this is the setup I have in my version. I add ImageIcons to JLabels which are added to JPanels which are then added to a master JPanel. This set up may not be ideal, but my GUI is working well with it. Which is why I'm trying to test the highlighting with the same conditions.